# What will happen when we declare cin as int and take input from cin with print cin in cout?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int cin;
    cin >> cin;
    cout << "cin is : " << cin;
}
```

In this code it gets different output in different complier and can't find proper solution.

Comment: You can replace all `cin`'s in your code with arbitrary identifier, nothing will change. `cin >> cin` does nothing (it computes a bit shift and ignores it), and `cout<<"cin is : "<<cin;` prints your variable; since the variable is uninitialized, the code prints arbitrary value.

Comment: @dyukha I got '0' as output in decoder compiler but when I compiled with visual studio 12 it gives 'run time error'

Comment: What VC version? It should not crash. It should print garbage in release.

Comment: @ZDF version 11.0.50727.1 RTMRET 
Visual Studio Professional 2012

Comment: @ZDF version 11.0.50727.1

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: The variable 'cin' is being used without being initialized

Comment: Actually it's question of snippets mcq so they gave four and explanation but not satisfied with it

Comment: This is normal. You should either initialize cin or tweak project's options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you probably don't understand: **scope** and **initialization**.

1. In the code below the global variable `v` is **hidden** by local variable `v` declared in `main`. All operations in `main` are performed on `main`'s `v`. The same is true for `cin`. The `cin` you declared in `main` is not the same `cin` declared in `std` namespace. So, `cin >> cin;` has a different meaning. You probably expected the same behaviour as `std::cin >> cin;`.

   ```
   double v;
   int main()
   {
     int v;
   }
   ```
2. c++ allows uninitialized variables. When you write `int cin;` memory space is allocated for `cin`, but **nothing is written in** (the variable is not automatically initialized). Leaving a variable uninitialized may be on purpose or not. Your compiler may be set to warn on uninitialized variables and/or check at run time. If you compile in debug configuration the variables may be automatically set to zero, depending on compiler, but you should not rely on this as your final build will be in release.

The answer to your question *"Garbage value, Error, Segmentation fault, Nothing is printed"* is **garbage value** (is this an interview question?):

- `cin` is a local integer variable and
- `cin >> cin` is different from `std::cin >> cin` and different from `cin >>= cin`.

Comment: I don't think there's a guarantee that accessing an uninitialized variable is guaranteed to print garbage. It's undefined behavior instead.

Comment: It is the only one that fits the question.

Comment: But it's still undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, it is, but you have to choose between the four options above. _"Garbage value"_ is the closest. _"Error"_ - I do not think the question was about compiler settings. _"Segmentation fault"_ - the program will, obviously, not crash. It will just display whatever the content of `cin` is - some nonsense (zero, if you are lucky).

Comment: This question is asked in cdac cat exam and I didn't found  proper solution for this because different compiler gives an different output

Comment: Declaration does not imply initialization, according to standard. In other words, it does not say what value the local variable `int cin;` should contain. The compiler implementer is free to take any decision wishes.

Comment: your answer is helpful to me but not completely satisfy

Answer (score 0):

Your code *invokes undefined behavior*. (Look up that term, it's an important concept that makes C++ an unreliable programming language.)

In the line `int cin`, you define a variable and don't initialize it.

The undefined behavior happens as soon as you read from the uninitialized `cin` variable.

The next undefined behavior happens depending on the value of `cin`. The shift-right operator is an arithmetic operation. If its right-hand side is not between 0 and the bit size of the left operand, [the behavior is undefined](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/195d5bab790c05c5f049c490b0af28fe1b94c22d/source/expressions.tex#L5834).

Comment: Garbage value, Error, Segmentation fault, Nothing is printed 
What should be the expected from these four?

Comment: As I said, read about the concept of _undefined behavior_. My guess is that all your files will be encrypted, and the encryption key be thrown away afterwards.

Answer (score -4):

you cannot declare keywords name for variable-name. cin and cout are keywords in c++.Please use different name for variable-name which used in your c++ program.

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are not reserved keywords. They are objects declared in the `std` namespace in `<iostream>`, and objects can't be keywords. Plus, the whole point of namespaces is to allow duplicate names in different naming scopes. So it is perfectly valid (albeit not recommended) to declare a user-defined variable named `cin`